# Microphone that can stand a k70rgb brown keyboard

Tags: microphone, keyboard, microphone-technique

So about half a hear ago I bought the at2020usb+. I was really happy with it but it kept annoying me that it picked up my keyboard, which is the corsair k70rgb brown. Now I know it is sorta clicky on it's own, that's why I have the brown switches.

Now today my mic broke. It is connected properly to my computer but it doesn't get recognized by my computer. And the driver isn't on the device manager setting either. I tried restarting my computer, plugging my mic out, switching usb port which worked but only for a little while, then broke again. I also tried finding the driver online with no sucess and updating all my drivers with driver booster. Nothing worked, I asked my retailer for help at their website, I told a help guy what I told you, and he sakd I could return it and get my money back. I now see this as an opportunity to get away my keyboard noise with a higher end mic (hopefully).

I've looked up a few mics and perhaps with a xlr mic with an interface it's possible to remove the keyboard sound but still having my voice (No I'm not puttong a towel over my keyboard :p ). Btw I already have a mic boom arm. I am thinking maybe a at2020 xlr or 2035 xlr with a scarlet 2i2 interface? Thanks for all the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

An interface will not change anything.

What are you using this mic for? Recording music, podcasts, or gaming? Do you need the most perfect vocal quality?

The reason you hear your keyboard is because your mic is a condenser mic. This type of mic is highly sensitive and used exclusively for recording. Mine will pick up birds chirping outside my apartment.

There are two types of mic, condenser, and dynamic. A dynamic mic requires and can handle much more sound pressure, and it also requires very close proximity to trigger.

http://www.sweetwater.com/insync/studio-microphone-buying-guide/

If you ask me, I recommend you get a dynamic mic with audio interface.

This mic is great [http://www.amazon.com/Blue-Microphones-enCORE-100-Studio-Grade/dp/B002SQJL9U?ie=UTF8&keywords=blue%20encore%20100&qid=1463323095&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SQJL9U)

Answer (score 1):

Just get a [Noise Gate Software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/noisegator/) (Info : [Noise Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_gate)) and set the threshold to where the keyboard is not picked up, also try to take away the microphone from the table the keyboard is on to cause less handling noise (if you haven't done that already).

Last, try to be consistent to how you type and talk, if you start typing very loudly the noise gate will open if you start talking too lightly the noise gate wont open.

So it's fairly easy but you also have to understand the principles that a noise gate is working on!